# non system font on whole page - bad idea?

Tags: fonts, font-face, webfonts

A client wants to add a webfont for their whole site (all the body text, sub menus, etc).

Normally as you know its usually only titles, main nav, straplines, etc.

Is there any major performance issues here? Not sure if I like the idea of the whole site being in a non-system font.

Adi.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a great idea to be honest. Apart from not being reliably supported, it can cause a slight performance hit on the client.

I assume you're talking about the use of @font-face?

Because sometimes you can notice a slight delay/flicker between the default font being rendered and being replaced by your web font. Also, if the font you use has a full international character set (includes accents, symbols etc.) then it may take longer - and drain bandwidth.

That said, it's a neat effect and is being more widely used these days. If your site is an 'arty' one rather than a functional one then you may just get away with it!

Comment: @font-face, yeah. Suppose best to test it and look at firebug results to see if its a mahor drain. Ta